# Mocking a generic protected method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, justmock

```
public class BaseClass
{
     protected static bool GetSomething<T>(HttpWebRequest request, out T response)
     {

     }
}


public class Class
{
     public bool DoSomething(string arg1, string arg2, out string reason)
     { 

          if (GetSomething(request, out response))
          {

          }  

     }
}
```

I'm trying to test DoSomething, but in order to do that I need to mock GetSomething. I can't seem to be able to mock it unless I change the GetSomething method so that it isn't generic.  If I do that, the following works:

```
var successfullResponse = new Response { Status = AuthenticationStatus.Success };
Mock.SetupStatic(typeof(Class));
Mock.NonPublic.Arrange<Class>("GetSomething", ArgExpr.IsAny<HttpWebRequest>(), ArgExpr.Out(successfullLoginResponse));

string reason;
var classInstance = new Class();
bool result = classInstance.DoSomething(arg1, arg2, out reason);
Assert.IsTrue(result);
Assert.IsNull(reason);
```

Shouldn't the same call work when GetSomething is generic?  If not, how can I mock GetSomething?

*We've submitted a ticket to Telerik. I'll update this post as soon as I discover anything.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic methods can be arranged through the reflection API, like so:

```
var getSomething = typeof(BaseClass)
       // get GetSomething<T> using reflection
       .GetMethod("GetSomething", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static) 
       // make it into GetSomething<Response>
       .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Response)); 

// and arrange
Mock.NonPublic.Arrange<bool>(method,
        ArgExpr.IsAny<HttpWebRequest>(),
        ArgExpr.Out(successfullLoginResponse))
   .Returns(true);
```